# Android Studio - Image asset without border

Tags: android-studio

When I create a new image asset in Android Studio it has a white border on all four sides.

What setting should I use to avoid this ?

What I have done currently is to directly copy the images into drawable folder and use that image. This works but I don't get the flexibility of the multiple image that is generated when I use the create image asset.

Comment: You can edit your question and put this comment there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are you speaking about this one:

[image]

Then all you can try to play with **Shape**, e.g.

[image]

BTW, there is **Background** parameter, too: you can choose any colour instead of white, if you wish.

Comment: I had to use a scroll bar on the right of the options to actually see the rest of the options like "shape", failed to notice it at first...